# using the toggle in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, toggle

1. I am using ionic toggle in my app, to give access to user,when the toggle is checked-on the permission status is changed in DB. But when the app is closed and re-opened again toggled is checked to off but the access permission changed in the DB remains the changed. I tried to keep the toggle checked-on but couldn't get it right.So i need help in keeping the toggle checked-on whenever the app is re-opened, so that i can know who are given access permission.
2. And also what to know if I check-out the toggle will the permission get changed to 'No Access' automatically?.

html:

```
 <ion-toggle  ng-model="numbers.checked" ng-repeat="numbers in phoneList" ng-change="change(numbers)" toggle-class="toggle-positive">
                {{numbers.userId}}
            </ion-toggle>
```

controller:

```
  $scope.change= function (obj) {
           $scope.userId=obj._id;
           console.log($scope.userId);
           var UpdateRole={'_id':$scope.userId,'role':'permit'};
           adminService.accessAdminPhone(UpdateRole,function(err,response){
               console.log('Passed thro Controller');
               console.log(UpdateRole);
           });
```

Service:

```
  var UpdateAdminAccess = function (UpdateRole,callback) {
            $http({
                method:'POST',
                url: urlEdit + 'auth/accessPermission',
                data: UpdateRole
            }).success(function (data, response, headers, config) {
                    callback(response);
                    console.log("successfully updated");
                }).error(function(data,status,error, headers,config){
                    callback(error);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(data);
                })
        };
        adminAccess.accessAdminPhone= UpdateAdminAccess;
        return adminAccess;
    });
```

Comment: so your problem is even the toogle is on in your db....view is showing off on reopening your app right

Comment: Yes that's the problem @SaEChowdary

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not fetching data while page loading from db....

while loading the page you have to call data from db ....show the toggle according toggle status ..... if the user performs any changes then you need to update it.

So that if the user made any changes you will change it in db.....and if you reopen the page due to  calling  data from db on page load you can found his status here and you can show his mode according to that data